# How to pass value from adapter class to fragment activity

Tags: android

```
public static String receiverId ;
public class Notifcationadapter extends BaseAdapter {

public static 
    DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager(context);
    ArrayList<Notify> notifies;

    public Notifcationadapter(Context context, ArrayList<Notify> notifies) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.notifies = notifies;

    }

    /* private view holder class */
    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDesc;
        ImageView yesimage;

        ImageView noimage;
        TextView revresetime;

        TextView rejected;
        ImageView notificationuserimage;
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        final DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager(context);
        final String isRead = notifies.get(position).getNotificationIsRead();
        final String dateTime = notifies.get(position)
                .getNotificationDatetime();
        final String desc = notifies.get(position).getNotificationDescrpiton();
        final String id = notifies.get(position).getNotificationId();
        receiverId = notifies.get(position).getNotificationRecieverID();
        ((HomeActivity) context).NotifcationRecciverid = notifies.get(position)
                .getNotificationRecieverID();
        ((HomeActivity) context).nOtifcationMessge = notifies.get(position)
                .getNotificationDescrpiton();

        final String senderId = notifies.get(position)
                .getNotificationSenderID();
        final String serverId = notifies.get(position)
                .getNotificationServerId();
        final String status = notifies.get(position).getNotificationStatus();
        final String type = notifies.get(position).getNotificationType();
}
}
```

This is My code of Adapter class am able to get value from database of receiver id i want to pass  this value to another actvity so that i can compare it but am getting null value when i pass to another :

am using like this :

```
String value =Notifcationadapter.receiverId;
        markerOptions.title(datamodel.contactName);
        if (datamodel.id
                .equals(Notifcationadapter.receiverId)) {
            markerOptions
                    .snippet(((HomeActivity) getActivity()).nOtifcationMessge);
            map.addMarker(markerOptions).showInfoWindow();

        } else {
            markerOptions.snippet(datamodel.phoneNumber);
            // Adding marker on the Google Map
            map.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }

    }
```

this code am using to compare value but here am getting value  null of receiver id please help suggest me where am doing wrong please tell me how i will pass value from one to another

Answer (score 0):

I think your receiverId is not initialized because the getView() method if not called yet when you use it in another Activity. Your can pass your receiverId by using Broadcast.

You can send a broadcast use the following code when you get your reciverId:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.youpkgname.getReciverId");
intent.putExtra(key, reciverId);
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Then, you can receive the receiverId in the other Activity by register a BroadcastReceiver and do what you want with it:

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // get the receiverId from intent here, and do what you want with it
            }
}, new IntentFilter("com.youpkgname.getReciverId"));
```

Comment: @user2794306 Though it's dynamic, you need to handle them one by one, right?

Comment: The method sendBroadCast(Intent) is undefined for the type Context  error is coming

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo problem. It's sendBroadcast , I've corrected it.

Comment: The method registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){}, IntentFilter) is undefined for the type FragHome  now thsi Error is coming

Comment: Make sure your FragHome is an Activity or any class that extends ContextWrapper which implement that method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61896/discussion-between-leog-and-user2794306).

Answer (score 0):

Add `view.setTag(receiverId);` in `getView(..);` and `view.getTag()` in the class where you require this
Hop it helps!!